# Extract bundled gems into system gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

This might sound as a strange thing to do. Is there a bundler way to extract the bundled gems (from a Gemfile or from .bundle) and install them as system gems outside of the bundler context?

Something like `bundle package`, but instead of caching them in vendor/cache, installs them as system gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new bundler does this by default

Answer (score 0):

When you run `bundle install` your gems are installed to your `BUNDLE_PATH` (which defaults to `~/.bundle`.

You can pass an argument specifying where you want to install your gems to; `bundle install /usr/local/lib/bundle`. From the user manual, "Further bundle commands or calls to Bundler.setup or Bundler.require will remember this location".

Of course, you'll need to use `sudo` to install to a system directory.

Is that what you're after?